audio.duration is not trustworthy?
I have a JS program that plays an audio until the very end.
I noticed than audio.duration slightly changes at the end of the audio, seemingly to have 0 <= audio.currentTime <= audio.duration always hold true :
let audio = new Audio(...)
audio.play()
function printAudioDuration() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    console.log(audio.duration)
    printAudioDuration()
  )
}
printAudioDuration()

That results in :
132.623667
132.623667
132.623667
...
132.623667
132.623673

And if I print audio.currentTime along the way, I always get a timestamp smaller than 132.623667, except for the last one, which exactly equals 132.623673.
Is this a documented behavior ? Am I doing something wrong ?

That results in : is that the duration or the currentTime? - how does 6 microseconds effect your code?

It's the duration, see the code. And it affects my code since I assume it immutable (it is even declared readonly in typescript) in several places - but knowing why I care about this is not the point here.

Are you intending to use two <=  operators like that?

No, and that's still not the point. I just want to know whether or not it is normal for that snippet of code to produce that result, and if yes, why.

it is even declared readonly it is, your code can't change it - I've seen this before, I'm sure I read that the duration is approximated (very well in most cases) - I can't find any documentation to back that up though. You could write your code so that it only treats milliseconds as significant :p

Yes, it is documented that the duration can be changed and there is an event posted if it is changed.
The duration can be NaN, +Infinity or a finite number.
From the documentation

When the length of the media resource changes to a known value (e.g.
from being unknown to known, or from a previously established
length to a new length) the user agent must queue a media element
task given the media element to fire an event named durationchange at
the media element.

